# Partial data is getting generated in html report

Tags: jmeter, robotframework

jtl file contains 2 testcase but when i generate html report using the same only the  data of latest entry is populating in html report,

**Command used for Report generation:**

```
sh jmeter.sh -g /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/logs/log.jtl -f -o /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/Output/
```

**Getting below message in terminal after executing above command,**

File '/home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/logs/log.jtl' does not contain the field names header, ensure the jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties are the same as when the CSV file was created or the file may be read incorrectly when generating report

**JTL data:**

```
 1619015828359,121,aws_sns,200,,Thread2 2-1,text,true,,422,592,1,1,http://10.77.2.208:8080/graphql,117,0,66
1619015831675,137,solutionsinfini,200,,Thread2 2-1,text,true,,422,600,1,1,http://10.77.2.208:8080/graphql,130,0,65
```

Below is the screenshot of html report
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the same [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) for JMeter instance(s) which:

- run the test
- generate the [reporting dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

any inconsistencies will result in failure or data loss

Particularly in your case the "problematic" property which doesn't match is `jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names`, try modifying your command to set this property to `false` via `-J` command-line argument as:

```
sh jmeter.sh -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=false -g /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/logs/log.jtl -f -o /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/Output/
```

in order to make the change permanent put the following line to *user.properties* file of your JMeter installation:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=false
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)